# Safari not playing h.264 videos from ubuntu server

Tags: macos, ubuntu, video, safari

I am working on a django project where I am uploading webm and mp4 videos, embedding them using video tag (HTML5). In Firefox, chrome and IE 10 the videos are playing properly. But in Safari 10.1.2, I am not able to play h.264/mp4 videos. This is strange to me as I could load mp4 video from https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/tests/video.html from safari.

Secondly, I tried the ClickToFlash plugin of safari which gives a flash fallback option. But this is also not working.

Thirdly, Quicktime plugin for safari has also been activated, but it seems to have no use.

I am coming to a conclusion if I am missing something at server end. I am using Ubuntu server.

Please guide on how to enable mp4 videos on safari browser.

Comment: Is the server returning the correct mime type?

Comment: How to check that? I have added type="video/mp4" in video tag. Is it something different than that?

Comment: Do a GET with curl or something and see what the server is returning.

Comment: I used the command 'curl -s -I path-to-mp4-video | grep "^Content-Type:"' and it is returning nothing.

Comment: I also used curl -I path-to-mp4-video, it is returning Content-Type: video/mp4.

Comment: Are you able to provide a link to an example video - there are some subtle safari and server interactions which it may be possible to see with an example?

Comment: The example video link is https://quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4. This plays on safari directly. But If I download this video and embed it in HTML5 video container, it doesn't work. Also, If I try to directly play the server link of the video from safari, it doesn't work.